Python json.dumps of a tuple with some UTF-8 characters, either fails or converts them. I want the encoded character retained as is
On my server, a Python script gets data from a database as a tuple. Then the script converts the tuple to a string (using json.dumps()) to be passed to the JavaScript script in the user's browser.
The data include German names such as Weidmüller. When the Python scrip gets that data, it returns it as Weidm\xfcller, where \xfc is the UTF-8 encoding of ü. So far so good.
However,

json.dumps(tableData,ensure_ascii=False) converts the \xfc to �
json.dumps(tableData,ensure_ascii=True) fails: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5: invalid start byte"

What I really want is for json.dumps to leave the UTF-8 encoded character alone; to just pass the \xfc as is. That way the JavaScript script in the user's browser can do the decoding.
Is that possible?
Or, am I approaching the problem incorrectly?
Here is the complete code:
import MySQLdb

...


    # Open the data base and return a handle to it and its cursor
    dataBase, dbCursor = database.OpenDB()

    # Get data from the URL
    fieldStore = cgi.FieldStorage()
    selFieldName = selFieldValue = ''
    sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM %s' % (database.CompTableName)
    if ('fldName' in fieldStore) and ('fldValue' in fieldStore):
        fldName = fieldStore['fldName'].value
        fldValue = fieldStore['fldValue'].value
        sqlQuery += ' WHERE %s = \'%s\'' % (fldName,fldValue)
    if ('max' in fieldStore):
        maxRows = fieldStore['max'].value
        sqlQuery += ' LIMIT ' + maxRows
     # Get the selected data in the table as a list of lists 
    rowsAffected = dbCursor.execute(sqlQuery)
    tableData = dbCursor.fetchall()
    # Close the database and return the results
    dataBase.close()
    
    jsonTableData = json.dumps(tableData,encoding='latin1',ensure_ascii=True)
    print jsonTableData

And here is test code:
    tableData = (('item1', 'Jones',), ('item2', 'Weidm\xfcller'))
    jsonTableData = json.dumps(tableData,encoding='latin1',ensure_ascii=True)
    print jsonTableData


Are you dumping bytes‽ You should have the character ü, not \xfc in any form.

"Are you dumping bytes‽ " I don't know what "dumping" means, sorry.  Do you mean "converting"? "in any form" It's not a form, it's a database.

Dumping = json.dumps

Thank you for the explanation. No, I am not "dumping" bytes. I am "dumping" a tuple.

And that tuple contains what exactly? Bytes? Where do they come from? A database adapter should ideally return text, str, then this should be a nonissue.

"And that tuple contains what exactly? " Example: (('item1', 'Jones',), ('item2', 'Weidm\xfcller')). "A database adapter should ideally return..." a tuple that includes strings.  sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM %s' % (database.TableName)   ...  dbCursor.execute(sqlQuery) ... tableData = dbCursor.fetchall() That returns a tuple.

What database adapter is that? Also, what Python version? Are you using Python 2 perchance? Please provide a [mre].

MySQLdb. Python 2, yes.

@DavideAndrea It’s not valid JSON if it isn’t encoded in UTF-8. [Edit] your question with a reproducible example.

If using Python 2, 'Weidm\xfcller' is correct and contains the escape code for ü. print it to see it correctly.

@Mark Tolonen. TIL that only UTF-8 is acceptable in JSON strings. Thank you. I will now re-examine the issue in a different light. "a reproducible example" Hard to do when it involves access to a database: I would have to post the login credentials. I can't so that, sorry.

@David no you just set a variable with minimal content and show how you write the json to a file. No db required

\xfc is not the UTF-8 encoding of ü, it's the latin-1 encoding.
>>> u'ü'.encode('latin-1')
'\xfc'
>>> u'ü'.encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\xbc'

If you json.dumps text, you shouldn't get replacement characters like that:
>>> json.dumps({u"k": u"Weidmüller"})
'{"k": "Weidm\\u00fcller"}'
>>> json.dumps({u"k": u"Weidmüller"}, ensure_ascii=False)
u'{"k": "Weidm\xfcller"}'

Check to make sure that what you're getting from the database is correctly decoded text in the first place.

"it's the latin-1 encoding" Thank you. That's what I needed. I solved it with json.dumps(tableData,encoding='latin1',ensure_ascii=True)

@DavideAndrea It’s not valid JSON if it isn’t encoded in UTF-8.

@DavideAndrea That is not the "solution" I wanted you to arrive at from this answer. You should prefer to make sure that your tuples contain unicode items, not str items. That means configuring your database adapter correctly.

@wim I will reassess my approach based on your advice. Thank you.
